# BASH: Find number in text -> variable

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I need little help from the community:

I have these two lines in a large text file:

```
Connected clients: 42  
4 ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST 20 SECONDS
```

How I can find, extract and assign the numbers to variables?

```
clients=42
active=4
```

SED, AWK, GREP? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clients=$(grep -Po '^(?<=Connected clients: )([0-9]+)$' filename)
active=$(grep -Po '^([0-9]+)(?= ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST [0-9]+ SECONDS$)' filename)
```

or

```
clients=$(sed -n 's/^Connected clients: \([0-9]\+\)$/\1/p' filename)
active=$(sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\) ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST [0-9]\+ SECONDS$/\1/p' filename)
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Unfortunatelly, only one work, the active line with the grep. Why the first "clients" line with grep not work? The solution with sed, also not working. Here is the text file: http://d.pr/tVhg+

Comment: @Adrian: The commands in my answer are very restrictive. You can loosen them up by removing the anchors `^` and `$`. They are also constrained by the embedded spaces. You can change each space within the string to `[[:blank:]]*`. You can also try shortening the strings to whatever part is essential for being unambiguously selective. Do you get error messages or it just fails to match?

Comment: grep -Po '(?<=Connected clients: )([0-9]+)' mi AND
  
grep -Po '^([0-9]+)(?= ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST [0-9]+ SECONDS$)' mi  ... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
str='Connected clients: 42 4 ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST 20 SECONDS'

set -- $str
clients=$3
active=$4
```

---

If it's two lines, fine.

```
str1='Connected clients: 42'
str2='4 ACTIVE CLIENTS IN LAST 20 SECONDS'

set -- $str1
clients=$3
set -- $str2
active=$1
```

Reading two lines from a file may be done by

```
{ read str1; read str2; } < file
```

---

Alternately, do the reading and writing in AWK, and slurp the results into Bash.

```
eval "$(awk '/^Connected clients: / { print "clients=" $3 }
             /[0-9]+ ACTIVE CLIENTS/ { print "active=" $1 }
            ' filename)"
```

Comment: Not the best. I have this two line in a big text file, between another text.  update: sorry, the string is two line, not one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk

```
$ set -- $(awk '/Connected/{c=$NF}/ACTIVE/{a=$1}END{print c,a}' file)
$ echo $1
42
$ echo $2
4
```

assign $1, $2 to appropriate variable names as desired

if you can directly assign using declare

```
$ declare $(awk '/Connected/{c=$NF}/ACTIVE/{a=$1}END{print "client="c;print "active="a}' file)
$ echo $client
42
$ echo $active
4
```